# Get attribute of first element using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

Trying to parse an XML file using lxml in Python, how do I simply get the value of an element's attribute? Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<item id="123">
    <sub>ABC</sub>
</item>
```

I'd like to get the result 123, and store it as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `etree.parse()`, simply call `.getroot()` to get the root element; the `.attrib` attribute is a dictionary of all attributes, use that to get the value:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
>>> tree.getroot().attrib['id']
'123'
```

If you used `etree.fromstring()` the object returned is the root object already, so no `.getroot()` call is needed:

```
>>> tree = etree.fromstring('''\
... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
... <item id="123">
...     <sub>ABC</sub>
... </item>
... ''')
>>> tree.attrib['id']
'123'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use an XPath selector:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<item id="123">
    <sub>ABC</sub>
</item>''')
>>> tree.xpath('/item/@id')
['123']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Martijn has answered your question. Building on his answer, you can also use the `items()` method to get a list of tuples with the attributes and values. This may be useful if you need the values of multiple attributes. Like so:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
>>> item = tree.xpath('/item')
>>> item.items()
[('id', '123')]
```

Or in case of string:

```
>>> tree = etree.fromstring("""\
... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
... <item id="123">
...     <sub>ABC</sub>
... </item>
... """)
>>> tree.items()
[('id', '123')]
```